# Update multiple columns with data retrieved from multiple rows of same table

Tags: sql, database, db2

For the following data:

```
PGM      INC        EXC
First    A          AA
First    B          BB
First    C          CC
First    D          DD

Second   E          EE
Second   F          FF
Second   G          GG
Second   H          HH
```

How can we sequentially read column data of PGM='First' and update into Columns of PGM='Second'

```
PGM      INC        EXC
Second   E          AA
Second   F          BB
Second   G          CC
Second   H          DD
```

Here as we can see PGM='Second' has mapped the same data of PGM='First' for the 4 rows. How can this be achieved in a single update query of such multiple records.

Please guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea is to use the row_number window function to assign 1, 2, 3 etc in order to the two sets. You can then join these to figure out which value from set 1 should apply to which value in set 2.

Here's a lowest common denominator method that works on Postgres/Oracle/SQL Server. I don't have access to DB2 to try it.

if there aren't enough values in First, then the end values for second will be overwritten with null

```
Update
    test
Set
    Exc = (
        Select
            f.Exc
        From (
            Select
                Exc,
                row_number() over (order by inc) as rn
            From
                test
            Where
                Pgm = 'First'
        ) as f
        inner join (
            Select
                Inc,
                row_number() over (order by inc) as rn
            From
                test
            Where
                Pgm = 'Second'
        ) as s
            On f.rn = s.rn
        Where
             test.inc = s.inc
    )
Where
    test.Pgm = 'Second';
```

**<kbd>[Example Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a8844/3)</kbd>**

Comment: Thanks for the response.May i have a li'l explanation over d above variables f,s,rn, t

Comment: I'd quite need a brief explanation on the above query before I could actually fire it over my db..Wondering over the WITH keyword above as well for DB2.

Comment: @techie just do `begin transaction - my query, select * from table, rollback transaction` - instant sandbox.

Comment: DB2 wouldn't allow me a begin transaction :(..the above update query looks hopeful lemme just fire and check

Comment: @techie I've included a link to SQLFiddle now - it works as written on other platforms. Oh, and DB2 for `begin transaction` is `start transaction`

Comment: Awesome!Worked seamlessly..Just one more, incase i would like INC and EXC both to pick values of First into Second, what amends do i need to make?

Comment: @techie http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a8844/5 This looks less ugly if you can use `With`, but I don't think DB2 supports it in an update statement.